# Time complexity of hierarchical algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hierarchical

I am looking for the time complexity of the algorithm that I will explain below. Thank you for helping me....please!

This algorithm consists of two general steps:

1. Get the nearest neighbor :

For each node, it only looks at the direct neighbor and finds the nearest neighbor (shortest distance) through the following formula.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVMq9.png)

which VG is the total degree of each node .and I is the corresponding element of the Moore-Penrose
inverse matrix of laplacian

It continues in this way until a chain of nodes with the nearest neighbor is created. Finally, the chain stops when two nodes close to each other are found in this chain and have the least amount of distance to each other in the cluster. These two nodes are considered as representatives of the cluster.

2. Pruning the node:

After the formation of each cluster, the depth of each node is calculated with respect to the two representative nodes of that cluster, and if the depth of each node with respect to the two representative nodes is greater than the desired threshold, that node is pruned and considered as a single-member cluster.

Comment: Specifying an algorithm starts with defining its inputs. Your first phrase is "For each node, it only looks at the direct neighbor...."  What are these nodes? You can't expect a useful answer if the question skips such a basic part.

Comment: Consider the input dataset as a graph where each node is connected to its neighbors through an edge.

Comment: Each node can be an entity such as a user or anything else that is connected to its nearest neighbor through an edge.

Comment: Please read [the help on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and edit yours to add this info.

Comment: This is a directed graph, with double edges of different weight possible?   For those of us who don't work with Moore-Penrose inverse Laplacians every day, it would be nice to have this stated.  Also, complexity will depend on data structures used.  Should the answer propose efficient structures or a simple adjacency matrix?

Comment: Link to this article is :https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Hierarchical+Clustering+Supported+by+Reciprocal+Nearest+Neighbors&btnG=

Comment: this is a Undirected graph and unweighted

Comment: It is weighted afaics. D(i, j) is the weight of the edge from i to j, no?  If so, then the graph is undirected iff D is symmetric. Else it's a directed graph where edge i->j has  a different weight than j->i.